# Helm installed container rejects port that works with Docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes-helm

I'm starting the `helm create chart` with some mods to tell it to open up port 12800 to the outside world and send it to the internal pod. Via Helm, I get connection refused.

When I start the same container via Docker:

```
docker run --publish 12800:12800 gcr.io/rsi-api-test/rsi-api:latest
```

My test app can successfully hit localhost:12800/factorial/5 and give me my expected result.

In the Helm deployed version, at some point it gives up and says

```
Application availability state ReadinessState changed from ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
```

Why does it work as a normal Docker app, but Helm can't handle exposing the port?

Values.yml

```
replicaCount: 1
image:
  repository: gcr.io/rsi-api-test/rsi-api
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  tag: "latest"
imagePullSecrets: []
nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""
serviceAccount:
  create: true
  annotations: {}
  name: ""
podAnnotations: {}
podSecurityContext: {}
securityContext: {}
service:
  type: LoadBalancer 
  externalPort: 12800 
  targetPort: 12800
ingress:
  enabled: false
  className: ""
  annotations: {}
  hosts:
    - host: chart-example.local
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls: []
resources: {}
autoscaling:
  enabled: false
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 100
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 80
nodeSelector: {}
tolerations: []
affinity: {}
```

Chart.yml

```
apiVersion: v2
name: rsi-api
type: application
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: "1.16.0"
```

service.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ include ".helm.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include ".helm.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  type: {{ .Values.service.type }}
  ports:
    - port: {{ .Values.service.externalPort }}
      targetPort: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    {{- include ".helm.selectorLabels" . | nindent 4 }}
```

deployment.yaml (based off `helm create chart`, changed port only)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include ".helm.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include ".helm.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  {{- if not .Values.autoscaling.enabled }}
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  {{- end }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      {{- include ".helm.selectorLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
  template:
    metadata:
      {{- with .Values.podAnnotations }}
      annotations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      labels:
        {{- include ".helm.selectorLabels" . | nindent 8 }}
    spec:
      {{- with .Values.imagePullSecrets }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      serviceAccountName: {{ include ".helm.serviceAccountName" . }}
      securityContext:
        {{- toYaml .Values.podSecurityContext | nindent 8 }}
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          securityContext:
            {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 12800
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
      {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with .Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
```

Bonus points to tell me how I can see the exposed ports if it did work in Helm console output.

Comment: Kubernetes doesn't usually directly give external access to pods in the way `docker run -p` does.  What URL are you trying to connect to, and what part of this setup should make it visible?  Do you also have a Deployment (or StatefulSet) as part of this setup, and is the Service binding to it successfully?  It looks like you're requesting a LoadBalancer-type service, is your environment in fact creating a load balancer (hosted setups like AWS EKS will, minikube won't)?

Comment: @DavidMaze URL: http://localhost:12800. I thought the Service put out a publically reachable load balanced port at 12800 hitting the containers 12800 port. There is a deployment. Will post shortly. I'm trying first on minikube, then trying gcp. Minikube didn't make this lack of support obvious.